# How to convert char to digit in Assembly Irvine?

Tags: assembly, masm32, irvine32

I want to convert user's input character to digit(decimal) in Assembly MASM and Irvine library.

`CALL ReadChar        ; store user input in AL register
  -> c                ; user input character C

some code here to convert AL data to decimal 12

`

Comment: Write program, assenble and run. Do you have any questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the char
subtract a '0' from it
if after that, it's larger than 9,
and it with 0xBF (to lowercase 'A'-'F' to 'a'-'f') 
and subtract 7 again. 
et voilá, there's your value

Comment: AND with `~0x20` upcases.  the lower-case ASCII range has one extra bit set.  `'r'` = `'R' + 0x20` = `'R' | 0x20`.  (And yes this holds for all the alphabetic chars).  BTW, the question asks for decimal, in which case you stop after the `sub al, '0'` step.